# Bootstrap carousel not working in Heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I am using bootstrap from a CDN with my rails app. Most of the styling works except for the carousel on the home page. It works fine in development but not at Heroku. I don't know if this is relevant but I have defined this route in routes.rb: root "home#index" which displays index.html.erb via the HomeController. The first image in the carousel is loaded but that is it. It has no functionality. Right now I have no bootstrap gems in the gem file which I will try if necessary. I just wanted to see if anyone has seen this issue before and knows what to do. I think this file is OK since it works in development but here is index.html.erb:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide img-rounded" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
</ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<div class="item active">
  <%= image_tag("nicholson2.jpg", alt:"nicholson", class: "img-rounded") %>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <%= image_tag("marilyn2.jpg", alt:"marilyn", class: "img-rounded") %>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <%= image_tag("pacino2.jpg", alt:"pacino", class: "img-rounded") %>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <%= image_tag("lily.jpg", alt:"lily", class: "img-rounded") %>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <%= image_tag("deniro2.jpg", alt:"deniro", class: "img-rounded") %>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Left and right controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: it's easiest if you just post the link of the heroku app. My guess is that your heroku app isn't serving js assets.

Comment: It was a typo in my style tag. I had http: instead of https:

Comment: is this resolved then? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using https: instead of http: when linking to external resources. It works in development but evidently heroku does not allow it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in my case i had to remove the `//=require jquery_ujs` from the application.js file (`assets/javascripts/application.js`). Hopefully it will resolve the issue. :)